# Quick sort implementation in JavaScript in prototype style

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quick-sort, prototypal-class-design

I have implemented quickly the quick sort algorithm in JavaScript using prototype based style.

The code is rather short (http://jsfiddle.net/b8mfY/):

```
<script>

"use strict";

var Sort = function( inputArray ) {
    this.arrayTest = undefined;
    this.init( inputArray );
};
Sort.prototype.init = function( inputArray ) {
    if ( inputArray instanceof Array && inputArray.length > 0 ) {
        this.arrayTest = inputArray;
        this.DumpArray( this.arrayTest );
        this.QuickSort( this.arrayTest, 0, this.arrayTest.length - 1 );
        this.DumpArray( this.arrayTest );
    }
    else console.log( 'Input argument isn\'t an array object or its length equals zero.' );
};
Sort.prototype.QuickSort = function( data, first, last ) {
    var i = first;
    var j = last;
    var x = data[ Math.ceil( ( first + last ) / 2 ) ];

    do {
        while ( data[ i ] < x ) i++;
        while ( data[ j ] > x ) j--;

        if ( i <= j ) {
            if ( i < j ) {
                if ( data[ i ] !== data[ j ] ) {
                    var tempItem = data[ i ];
                    data[ i ] = data[ j ];
                    data[ j ] = tempItem;
                }
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }

    } while ( i <= j );

    if ( i < last ) this.QuickSort( data, i, last );
    if ( first < j ) this.QuickSort( data, first, j );
}
Sort.prototype.DumpArray = function() {
    var output = 'The content of array: [ ';

    if ( this.arrayTest instanceof Array && this.arrayTest.length > 0 ) {
        this.arrayTest.forEach( function( item ) {
            output = output.concat( [ item, ', ' ].join( '' ) );
        });
    }
    else console.log( 'Can\'t dump the input array. It\'s not an array object or its length equals zero.' );

    output = output.substring( 0, output.length - 2 );
    output = output.concat( ' ].' );
    console.log( output );
};

window.onload = new Sort([
    10,
    1,
    27,
    4090,
    100000,
    2222,
    4934
]);

</script>
```

I'm asking for a code review of the quick sort implementation part more than other details.

Answer (score 1):

Looks okay to me.

- I would probably go for `if ( i != j ) {` which could be faster than `if ( i < j ) {`
- You have a ton of short variable names, I guess that's ok for a sorting routine, though I would still rename `x` to `m`(iddle).
- I would have declared `tempItem` right under `i` and `j`

For the part you are not so interested in;

- Capital S in `Sort` is reserved for constructors
- I think `reduce` is more appropriate than `forEach` in `DumpArray`
- You should not put code on the same line after an `else` statement
- Now that I think about it the dump routine could be reduced to

  ```
  Sort.prototype.DumpArray = function() {

  var prefix = 'The content of array: [ ';
  //Duck typing, just test for join
  if( this.arrayTest.join )
      console.log( prefix + this.arrayTest.join(', ') + ' ]'  )
  else
      console.log( "Input: " , this.arrayTest );
  };
  ```